# Are git branch always to be merged?

Tags: git, repository, branch

*Before : My question is focused on Git philopsophy and best practice, not on technical POV.*

I wonder if a Git branch fate is to be eventually **merged all the time**. 
Will we stick to best practice using a branch to live it's own life without merging at any time to master, and knowing it at start?

Would it be better in this case to create an new repo with this branch content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch name is mostly just a name for a commit, just like a tag name.  There's no need to use it to make merge commits, though there's no compelling reason *not* to use it that way either.

When a name—including a branch name or a tag name—identifies some commit, such as the commit whose hash ID starts with `1234567...`, we say that this name *points to* that particular commit.  The "true name" of the commit is the hash ID, and *any number of (non-hash-ID) names*—zero, one, two, a million—can all point to that commit.  The hash IDs are terrible for humans to use (who can remember `a3c921fa60b7...` for more than a few seconds?) so we generally prefer names.  When a commit is particularly important, we might give it a name, or several names.

There is one very important way that a branch name is *not* like a tag name, though, and that is how Git behaves when you are "on" the branch, as in, when running `git status` says `on branch xyz`.  *In this case*, Git will *automatically* change the branch name so that it points, not to the commit that it pointed to just a moment ago, but instead, to the new commit you just made.

Hence, if you're on branch `xyz`, and it points to commit `1234567`, and you make a *new* commit, the name `xyz` no longer points to `1234567`.  Instead, it points to some new commit, maybe `fedcba9` for instance.  The *new* commit you just made, meanwhile, points back to commit `1234567`.  This is how branches grow.

Something special that *any* name does, for any commit, is to make sure that both you and Git can find that commit easily.  Having found *that* commit, you can have Git find that commit's parent.  Having found the parent, you can have Git find the grandparent.  Having found *that* commit, you can have Git keep going through history.

This *is* the history in the repository, and it's formed by these parent linkages between commits.  Branch names point to the *tip* commit of any given branch, and starting at that commit, you—and Git—can work your way back in time to every previous commit.  Every commit you visit, as you do this "walk back through time", is *reachable* from the branch tip, via this walk process.

When you run `git merge`, you can<sup>1</sup> make Git create a new commit that has not one but *two* parents.  These commits are called *merge commits*, and when you (or Git) do the walking through history, you (or Git) will visit *both* parents, and their grandparents and so on.  All of these commits are reachable from the branch tip that got you to this merge commit.

This reachability has the side effect of making sure that Git does not *remove* the commits.  All reachable commits are permanent.  All commits are read-only.  So whatever is in history, reachable from all branch tips, is stored forever: read-only and permanent, in the form of commits.

Once you merge branch `feature` into `mainline`, you can *delete* the name `feature`, because the name `mainline` either points to, or eventually reaches, the merge commit that points to the commits that were, earlier, only reachable from `feature`.  So after merging, you can delete a name.  But there's no need to merge: you can keep the name, which keeps the commits.

Or, if you have determined that there's no need for these commits ever, in the future, you can *delete* the name.  This makes the commits *unreachable*—well, by that name at least; there might still be some other name(s) that reach them.  If the commits are truly unreachable—if they have no branch name that finds them, no tag name that finds them, and no other name (such as `refs/stash`) that eventually allows Git to find them from a name—then at some point soon, when `git gc` runs, Git will actually remove those commits for real.

Hence, the answer is no: you don't *have* to merge a branch.  As long as you keep the name around, the name keeps all those commits preserved.  If you have merged the branch, some *other* name is now also keeping those commits preserved, so you *can* (but do not have to) delete the branch-name; but as long as you keep the branch name around, the commits stick around, whether merged or not.  Those commits are reachable from the tip of the branch: something Git sometimes calls *contained in* the branch.  (See `git branch --contains`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git merge` command does not always make merge commits.  Sometimes, it does a "fast forward", which is not really a merge.  You can tell it to `--squash`, which eventually makes an ordinary (non-merge) commit, too.  So `git merge` only makes merge commits *sometimes*.

Answer (score 1):

No. Using release branches is quite common: For every main release you do, you can for instance allow bugfixing on its release branch to create new sub-releases while your main development is done in parallel on the development branch.